# Lookup value from one dataframe and return in a new column the closest value from another column in another dataframe based on a common value

Tags: python, pandas

Sounds menacing but I'll make it clear.

I have 2 dataframes:

df1

```
    Group   Target  Sales
0   A   13432   5756
1   A   13443   17083
2   A   13462   17635
3   A   13501   10266
4   A   13377   18375
5   A   13417   13963
6   A   13448   16056
11  B   13539   13020
12  B   13567   18171
13  B   14501   12135
14  B   13608   12399
15  B   13578   7419
16  B   13555   9083
21  C   13556   12121
22  C   13576   11633
23  C   13693   23983
24  C   12501   17222
25  C   13670   10547
26  C   13614   10945
27  C   13497   10411
```

df2

```
    Group   NewTarget
0   A   13500
1   B   14500
2   C   12500
```

The common column is Group.

I'd like to do a lookup of sorts which looks up the 'NewTarget' value in df2 against the 'Target' value in df1 and returns the closest 'Sales' value as a new column 'New' in df1 by group. So the result would look like this:

df3

```
    Group   Target  Sales   New
0   A   13432   5756    10266
1   A   13443   17083   10266
2   A   13462   17635   10266
3   A   13501   10266   10266
4   A   13377   18375   10266
5   A   13417   13963   10266
6   A   13448   16056   10266
11  B   13539   13020   12135
12  B   13567   18171   12135
13  B   14501   12135   12135
14  B   13608   12399   12135
15  B   13578   7419    12135
16  B   13555   9083    12135
21  C   13556   12121   17222
22  C   13576   11633   17222
23  C   13693   23983   17222
24  C   12501   17222   17222
25  C   13670   10547   17222
26  C   13614   10945   17222
27  C   13497   10411   17222
```

Note I have many other numeric columns in df1, but trying to keep as simple as possible.

Appreciate the help.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, it seems you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You want [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with panda `merge_asof`

```
out1 = pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('NewTarget'),
                     df1.sort_values('Target'),
                     left_on = 'NewTarget',
                     right_on='Target',
                     by='Group',
                     direction = 'nearest')
out = df1.merge(out1.loc[:,['Group','Sales']],on='Group')
Out[615]: 
   Group  Target  Sales_x  Sales_y
0      A   13432     5756    10266
1      A   13443    17083    10266
2      A   13462    17635    10266
3      A   13501    10266    10266
4      A   13377    18375    10266
5      A   13417    13963    10266
6      A   13448    16056    10266
7      B   13539    13020    12135
8      B   13567    18171    12135
9      B   14501    12135    12135
10     B   13608    12399    12135
11     B   13578     7419    12135
12     B   13555     9083    12135
13     C   13556    12121    17222
14     C   13576    11633    17222
15     C   13693    23983    17222
16     C   12501    17222    17222
17     C   13670    10547    17222
18     C   13614    10945    17222
19     C   13497    10411    17222
```

Comment: For you too happy NY.

Comment: merge_asof did the trick. The first solution threw up a Keyword error for the new column name 'NewTarget'... Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Group', how='left')

df['NewTarget'] = (df.set_index('Sales')
               .assign(diff = lambda x: x['Target'].sub(x['NewTarget']).abs())
               .groupby('Group')['diff']
               .transform('idxmin')
               .to_numpy())
print (df)
   Group  Target  Sales  NewTarget
0      A   13432   5756      10266
1      A   13443  17083      10266
2      A   13462  17635      10266
3      A   13501  10266      10266
4      A   13377  18375      10266
5      A   13417  13963      10266
6      A   13448  16056      10266
7      B   13539  13020      12135
8      B   13567  18171      12135
9      B   14501  12135      12135
10     B   13608  12399      12135
11     B   13578   7419      12135
12     B   13555   9083      12135
13     C   13556  12121      17222
14     C   13576  11633      17222
15     C   13693  23983      17222
16     C   12501  17222      17222
17     C   13670  10547      17222
18     C   13614  10945      17222
19     C   13497  10411      17222
```

Comment: Ah happy new year ~